# Pandas: Efficient way of creating new column based on other column. Many to few

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, pandas, apply

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": [7001, 8001, 9001]} )
equiv = {1:[7001, 8001], 2: [9001]}
df["B"] = df["A"].map(equiv.get)
```

to end up with

```
a, b
7001, 1
8001, 1
9001, 2
```

I was thinking something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": [7001, 8001, 9001]} )
equiv = {1:[7001, 8001], 2: 9001}
df["B"] = df["A"].map(equiv.get)
```

I do not want to use `equiv = {7001:1, 8001:1, 9001:2}` because in my actual dataset I will have many string values that map to `1` and `2`

Comment: Why value `9001` is not in one element `list` like `[9001]` ?

Comment: @jezrael oh thanks for those typo catches!

Comment: I could put `9001` in a one element `list` but it wouldn't achieve my goal. Maybe that would look cleaner though... I'll update it!

Comment: Thanks. What do you think about solution change `dictionary of lists` to `inverted dictionary` and then use `map`? `d = dict( (v,k) for k in equiv for v in equiv[k] )` and `df["B"] = df["A"].map(d)`

Comment: I don't fully comprehend that... i'll have to google/think about it... but from my cursory understanding that might work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inverted dictionary` and then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( {"A": [7001, 8001, 9001]} )
print df
      A
0  7001
1  8001
2  9001

equiv = {1:[7001, 8001], 2: [9001]}

d = dict( (v,k) for k in equiv for v in equiv[k] )
print d
{7001: 1, 9001: 2, 8001: 1}

df["B"] = df["A"].map(d)
print df
      A  B
0  7001  1
1  8001  1
2  9001  2
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for!